# Получить текущий месяц на php c +1 или -1

Tags: php

Доброго! 
У меня есть конструкция:

```
$type = 1; // or $type = -1
$current_month = date('m');
$begin = mktime(0, 0, 0, $current_month, 1, date("Y"));
```

Нужно от текущего месяца отнять или же прибавить $type так чтобы результат $begin был правильный.
Как сделать?

Comment: Вам нужно номер предыдущего месяца получать, или что именно?

Answer (score 3):

```
<?
$type = -1;
$pos = $type > 0 ? '+' . $type : '-' . abs($type);
$begin = strtotime($pos . ' month');
echo "timestamp: " . $begin . "\n";
echo "formatDateNow: " . date('d-m-Y H:i:s') . "\n"; 
echo "formatDateForType: " . date('d-m-Y H:i:s', $begin) . "\n"; 
?>
```

Код на [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/wjYCdR)

В вашем методе есть один очень большой минус! На месяцах 1 и 12 у вас будут ошибки с переходом года и с месяцем (месяцев 0 и 13 не существует), если использовать **strtotime('- 1 month')** и **strtotime('+ 1 month')** этих ошибок не будет.

Comment: @ua6xh

вы неправы насчет 0 и 13 - php нормально это понимает

http://ideone.com/mC3oZV

в js, месяцы с 0, поэтому setMonth(0) - декабрь предыдущего, setMonth(12)  - январь следующего.

Comment: Может вот так подойдет:

    $type = 1;
    $d = date('Y-m-d');
    $begin = strtotime(($type >= 0 ? '+'.$type : $type).' months', strtotime($d));
    $current_month = date('m', $begin);

Для минуса соответственно пишите минус, или так:

Comment: eicto - я не фанат функции mktime, считаю её очень неудачной функцией в PHP, сейчас это ещё и подтвердилось вашим кодом, так как это не нормальное реагирование функции на такие входящие параметры.

Comment: почему вы считаете, что не нормальное ?  это не только mktime если что так работает. а так-же и объект [DateTime()](http://ideone.com/msEQc0) в js тоже похожее поведение.

Comment: Vot tak ne srabotalo:
$current_month = 10;
$begin = strtotime('+1 month');
echo  date($current_month, $begin); die();

Comment: Nujno polu4iti sleduiuwii mesyac ili prediduwii ot zadannogo

Comment: ну а чем вас не устраивает то ваше собственное решение ?

Answer (score 2):

А чем вам ваше же решение не понравилось ?

```
$type = 1; // or $type = -1
$current_month = date('m');
$begin = mktime(0, 0, 0, $current_month + $type, 1, date("Y"));
```

Будет возвращать то что вам нужно.