# Следующий месяц

Tags: php, дата

У меня переменная `$m_t` содержит значения от 1 до 12. Каждый раз мне нужно изменить эту переменную  на +1 или -1 но чтобы не вышло за рамки 1-12.
Замечу, что на выходе нужно получить только месяц!

Comment: про оператор if слышали? Говорят, полезная штука

Answer (score 1):

Уже ведь [отвечал](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/256050/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8F%D1%86-%D0%BD%D0%B0-php-c-1-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-1)